# OpenJPA dirty read hint

Tags: java, db2, openjpa

We've got the following DAO stack:

- DB2 9.7 Express-C
- OpenJPA 2.0.1
- Spring 3.0.5
- Bitronix 2.1.1

How do you specify OpenJPA to add `WITH UR` sql clause to the end of the query?

I'd browsed sites and manuals alike for days, it should be something like this:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select m from Magazine m where ... ");
q.setHint("openjpa.FetchPlan.ReadLockMode","WRITE");
List r = q.getResultList();
```

but alas, I've been unable to find a working OpenJPA property that would be passed as `setHint()` argument and yield `WITH UR` as result, so I use SpringJDBC queries which I unfortunately can't use any longer.

Any ideas? Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenJPA doesn't support using the `WITH UR` clause with JPQL. You could always use a [native query](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/latest/docs/manual/manual.html#jpa_overview_sqlquery) for this functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - do you have any links that explain this or document this?

Comment: Mada, you're telling me that OpenJPA supports the WITH UR syntax? Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having quite a similar problem now — it would seem that setting:

```
query.setHint("openjpa.FetchPlan.Isolation", "READ_UNCOMMITTED");
```

would do the trick. Unfortunately, the source code reveals that the constant `withURClause` from `org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary` is never read.

Additionally OpenJPA **never** takes into account a fetch plan hint if the query is not `FOR UPDATE`. I have a select statement that gets blocked on exclusive locks and it could really work with uncommitted data — a no-go with OpenJPA.

Comment: Please, don't guess. If you were to look at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DB2Dictionary.withURClause, you will notice that field is not referenced by the rest of the OpenJPA runtime code. While you may think that setting the FetchPlan.Isolation level would do the trick, it won't.

Comment: @Rick You were totally right. Now that I've taken a closer look it's really obvious. I'm sorry, I've already reverted the downvote and improved the answer.

Comment: @Quantum Please consider removing the downvote on this, now that the answer has been corrected. SO is about improvement, not retaliation.

Comment: @MaDa As far as I can see, I haven't downvoted your answer, nor I see any reason why would I. You have tried to correct an answer which you felt was wrong (though, admittedly, you could have done so with a bit more tact and carefulness), you have been proven wrong and have corrected yourself. In the end, everybody here has profited by gaining valuable knowledge, which is what this place is all about. So +1 from me for your efforts, though (as a friendly advice) do try to be more mindful in your answers in the future, especially if you're not 100% sure.

Comment: @Quantum I've been analysing the same bit of OpenJPA source code recently looking for a solution for a nasty deadlock, and I was initially quite excited at what I've found, hence the hasty answer. Rick's rebuttal showed there had been nothing to be excited about, my analysis had been too shallow. Thank you, your point is well taken.